# return No more messages in GLIGEN inference

Tags: stable-diffusion, multimodal, text2image

First,I download CLIP checkpoint in https://huggingface.co/openai/clip-vit-large-patch14/tree/main and change the path to /home/yuxiang/GLIGEN/pretrains/clip-vit-large-patch14.The code are as follows.

```py
    model = CLIPModel.from_pretrained(version).cuda()
    processor = CLIPProcessor.from_pretrained(version)
```

Then,I download GLIGEN checkpoint "Box+Text+Image" and change the path to             ckpt="/home/yuxiang/raida/gligen/checkpoint_generation_text_image.bin",

Finally,I run the code:

```py
        if meta['ckpt'] == "/home/yuxiang/raida/gligen/checkpoint_generation_text_image.bin":
            run(meta, args, starting_noise)`
and when it goes 
`    for phrase, image in zip(phrases,images):
        image_features.append( get_clip_feature(model, processor, image,  is_image=True) )
        text_features.append(  get_clip_feature(model, processor, phrase, is_image=False) )`

`def get_clip_feature(model, processor, input, is_image=False):
    which_layer_text = 'before'
    which_layer_image = 'after_reproject'

    if is_image:
        if input == None:
            return None
        image = Image.open(input).convert("RGB")
        inputs = processor(images=[image],  return_tensors="pt", padding=True)
        inputs['pixel_values'] = inputs['pixel_values'].cuda() # we use our own preprocessing without center_crop 
        inputs['input_ids'] = torch.tensor([[0,1,2,3]]).cuda()  # placeholder
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        feature = outputs.image_embeds 
        if which_layer_image == 'after_reproject':
            feature = project( feature, torch.load('projection_matrix').cuda().T ).squeeze(0)
            feature = ( feature / feature.norm() )  * 28.7 
            feature = feature.unsqueeze(0)
```

**outputs = model(**inputs)** it was blocked and no error was shown,I try to debug but it shows [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KXQo.png) .I don't know where I was wrong.

I want to run the code.

Comment: The GLIGEN github is https://github.com/gligen/GLIGEN